# Exim прием почты без суффикса после знака +

Tags: exim

Почтовый сервер Exim (ISPmanager lite):
имею ящик info@ но мне присылают письма на ящики info+2131 (после "+" может быть любое динамическое число). Как в такой ситуации всегда принимать письма на ящик info@ и отсечь суффикс?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115008/110559

Comment: local_part_suffix = +* : -*
local_part_suffix_optional

Comment: Эти опции не отрабатывают куда бы я их не добавил. Письмо все так же пытается отправить почту на info+222@ и говорит что такого пользователя не существует

Comment: вы [по ссылке](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_default_configuration_file.html#SECID55) проходили? там примеры есть. вставлять надо не куда угодно, а в конфигурацию соответствующего router-а(-ов). в вашем случае, как я понимаю, править нужно router под названием local_user. в debian при «раздельно-файловой» конфигурации это файл `/etc/exim4/conf.d/router/900_exim4-config_local_user`

Comment: local_users:
                driver = accept
                transport = local_delivery
                local_part_suffix = +*
    local_part_suffix_optional 
                condition = ${lookup {$local_part@$domain} lsearch {/etc/exim/passwd} {yes} {no} }

Comment: по ссылке переходил. Добавил две эти строки в конфиг файла /etc/exim/exim.conf  в раздел routes local_users

Comment: так [потрассируйте](https://github.com/Exim/exim/wiki/TestingExim). для начала: `exim -bt адрес`

Comment: делал возвращает маршрут и емейл info+22@ а  должен я так понимаю возвращать info@

Comment: exim должен написать, какой router использовал для этого адреса. вот этот router и надо исправлять.

Comment: Мой косяк не внимательности. Все работает после добавления local_part_suffix = +* : -* local_part_suffix_optional  подозреваю что не перезапускал службу в нужный момент( Спасибо - все работает

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в файл конфигурации exim.conf достаточно добавить следующие строки в раздел routes - local_users

```
 local_part_suffix = +* 
 local_part_suffix_optional
```

После этого обязательно перезагрузить службу exim